# WPF DataGrid virtualization not working properly?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, virtualization

I have a DataGrid which has a DataTable set as its ItemsSource.
The DataTable holds 24 columns and ~1600 rows (actually I will have to load alot more rows later on, but for now this is troublesome enough).

Despite setting virtualization for columns and rows active, the DataGrid takes around 30 seconds to display those 1600 rows.
After that, scrolling vertically works fine, horizontally is laggy, though you'd expect it the other way around.

If I run a memory profiler, I can verify that most of the memory used by the application comes from DataGridCells, Borders, ContentPresenters and Textblocks. To me, this indicates that the grid does not virtualize its rows properly.

Can anyone confirm that there's an issues with DataGrid's virtualization? Or is there some sort of infamous trap in the implementation of this control?

Looking forward to any kind of input/suggestions. Thanks :)

Comment: Are all columns standard columns, means text only or are some of them containing controls like `CheckBoxes` etc?

Comment: No, two of them are checkboxes.

Comment: Hmm, then give it a try and remove these two columns or change their appearance to "standard".

Comment: Made no difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved the issue.
My DataGrid was sitting inside a ScrollViewer, in which it would stretch infinitely. So it was fooled into thinking everything was visible, that's why it wouldn't virtualize its items.
I removed the ScrollViewer (DataGrid has scrollbars on its own anyway) and it works flawlessly now.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, ok I don't know why but obviously I've to add some glue text to post an answer here. Maybe, this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949358/datagrid-row-virtualization-display-issue) will help you.

**Edit**

As additional advice I'd like to recommend you to think about your approach. Is it really necessary to add 1.6k+ items to a `DataGrid`? Perhaps you should think about deferred loading.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about this. Strangely, a Winforms DataGrid seems to perform correctly.

Comment: Ok, what about the link in the answer?

Comment: Checkboxes don't seem to be the issue. Removing said columns didn't do the trick.

Comment: Yes, that helped, of course. But it's no use to me, I expect the user to scroll down a few hundred rows immediately.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot imagine a scenario, in which a user behaves that way. If you really have such an expactation, your approach of displaying these items seems to be not the best. Can't you filter the items to some criteria? Maybe, you just need to sort the items, so that it is not necessary to scroll immediately. I've serious doubts that your approach will provide a good usability not to mention the user experience...

Comment: Since the grid will show data gathered from many sources at 100hz (sources are accelerometers and CAN-bus), I can't do with a small amount of rows. Sure I can force the user to filter the results before displaying them, it'll still be several thousand rows in the end.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point. But regarding the usability, it makes no difference, if you display 250 or 5000 items in a table. The user cannot handle it. Because you won't display them all together. So you can think on another way to load the data or you can question the approach itself. What's the purpose of the view? Can't you provide the functionality in another way?

Comment: I guess you're right, I think I could try grouping samples. Guess I'll try to work around this for now. Thanks for your help, DHN.