# WPF DataGrid: Issue regarding virtualization of selected cells outside of visible area

Tags: c#, wpf, select, datagrid, virtualization

My `DataGrid` handles huge amounts of data (up to 40k rows on average), so I need to virtualize alot.

Occationally I need to select a whole bunch (if not all) of the cells within a certain column, to change their value collectively. I achieve this, for anyone interested, by handling a click on the column header (which usually sorts a column) and calling following method:

```
private void SelectColumn(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyDataGrid.SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
    {
        DataGridColumn column = e.Column;

        if (e.Column != null)
        {
            MyDataGrid.UnselectAllCells();

            for (int i = 0; i < MyDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.Add(new DataGridCellInfo(MyDataGrid.Items[i], column));
            }

            // Set the first cell into editing mode
            MyDataGrid.CurrentCell = MyDataGrid.SelectedCells[0];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I almost forgot to add my code for setting the value of the selected cells... :

```
private void MyDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyDataGrid.SelectedCells.Count > 1)
    { // More than 1 cell are selected
        if (e.EditingElement.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        { // The cell being edited is of type TextBox
            string value = ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text;
            foreach (DataGridCellInfo cellInfo in MyDataGrid.SelectedCells)
            {
                DataGridCell gridCell = TryToFindGridCell(MyDataGrid, cellInfo);
                if (gridCell != null) gridCell.Content = value; // ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text returns the Text in the cell sending DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e
            }
        }
    }
}

static DataGridCell TryToFindGridCell(DataGrid grid, DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
    DataGridCell result = null;
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cellInfo.Item);
    if (row != null)
    {
        int columnIndex = grid.Columns.IndexOf(cellInfo.Column);
        if (columnIndex > -1)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
            result = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex) as DataGridCell;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works very well if all of the selected cells are within the visible area of my GUI.
Since everything outside (with a few rows as a buffer) is being virtualized, though, I'm having issues. Virtualized rows aren't really selected, any cell outside the visible area doesn't change their value along with the visible ones.

Can anyone guide me to a better approach for this? And yes, I **need** to work with this amount of data, sorry. ;)

Comment: You [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958116/wpf-datagrid-virtualization-not-working-properly/14959136#14959136). ;o)

Comment: Sorry, haha. I think half of all questions about WPF DataGrid on SO right now are mine.

Comment: I don't know about virtualization, but I'm pretty sure that you can get a cell in a row if you know the column. Can't you just get all the cells this way?

Comment: This might not be the best of suggestion, but if assuming that the data backing the grid is an observable collection. It could make sense to get the edit value and modify the observable collection directly.

Comment: The data behind the grid is a DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had the same problem with WPF's datagrid.  It's just too slow.  I think it's because the datagridrow object is too bloated for this amount of data.

In my case, I had a very similar number of results I had to deal with.  I solved it by axing the datagrid entirely.  I hope your # of columns is constant, because it would be a pain (read: I'm not sure how :)) to implement this way if that's not the case...anyhoo...

Create a class and make a property for each column in your datatable

```
class TableItem
{
    public string Column1 { get; set: }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

etc....

Wherever you load your data from, iterate through the datatable/etc and add the columns to an ObservableCollection object in your viewmodel.

```
for (int = 0; i < yourDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = yourDataTable.Rows[i];
    TableItem ti = new TableItem 
    { 
        Column1 = row["Column1Name"].ToString(), 
        Column2 = row["Column2Name"].ToString()
    }
    yourObservableCollection.Add(ti);
}

ObservableCollectionInViewModel = yourObservableCollection;
```

Then create a ListView, and give it however many columns you need.  Bind the ListView to the ObservableCollection in your viewmodel we just created above, then use DisplayMemberBinding to bind each column to the corresponding property of the TableItem object:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstGridWOResourceHogging" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollecitonInViewModel, IsAsync="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column1Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column1}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Column2Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

This way, you turn virtualizing off and because it's not as fat as the datagrid's objects, the performance is much better.  Now, without virtualizing, what you select really is selected, and you can iterate through it with sanity.

Comment: Just to update, the ListView is faster, but still not "fast."  WPF's objects/dependency properties just inevitably take up too much memory and such when you need thousands of them (data rows).  If you really need it fast, Windows Forms Host will facilitate putting the Windows Forms DataGridView into a WPF app.