# WPF DataGrid, Enabling Row Virtualization causes losing selected rows and disabling it make it too slow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, virtualization

I have a WPF DataGrid with around 1000 rows. The WPF datagrid is in a form that is being hosted as a plugin in some other software.

**The goal:** is to improve the performance at least to some extent.

**The problem:** Enabling Row Visualization with either `VirtualizationMode="Standard"` or `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` causes losing selected rows when scrolling (the defect is sometimes subtle, I need to scroll many times to see the bug) and disabling it make it too slow.

**What have been tried so far:**

- I have tried taking care of selectivity using attached
  behaviours. I was successful to select rows one by one using a
  `LeftMouseClick` attached behaviour and a `DataTrigger` to change the
  color but my scenario is to have multi select available with Ctrl and
  Shift. So I am out of idea how to select/diselect multiple rows in
  that case.
- I've also tried to implement this (answer by denis morozov) 
  [DataGrid row virtualization display issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949358/datagrid-row-virtualization-display-issue)
  but I really did not understand it well.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I understand that the bug is subtle and non-deterministic but still.

Comment: Well, now I have it fixed with a very small anti-pattern trick (I did not have much time to think for the best solution). I added a SelectionChanged even handler for the grid to send the new and old selections to the ViewModel for updating my selected rows.