# Weird item "jumping" by WPF DataGrid scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid

I use WPF DataGrid with ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll property set to "True".

Items just "jumping" between the start and end of my items' list.

For example, the first item may accidentally appears at the end of list when I scroll to end. And when I scroll to start of list, it appears at start too.
By the way, I can't see the last item because the first item appears instead of last.

However, always visible items don't change its' order in list.

I tried set property ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to "False" and it works well, but it kills performance when I show big items' list at my DataGrid. 
Setting property EnableRowVirtualization to "False" produces same behavior.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks.
Nikolay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I added these properties to my DataGrid and it resolves my problem.

```
EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
```

Comment: I found the solution on that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949358/datagrid-row-virtualization-display-issue