# DataGrid with virutlaziation hyperlinks + normal text in column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have to display text and hyperlinks in a DataGrid column.
For this purpose I have created a DataTemplateColumn with a TextBlock.
In this text block I fill the Inlines property with the corresponding values.
Everything is displayed correctly as soon as I scroll down in the grid and the TextBlock gets out of sight, the bottommost TextBlock from the column is filled with the same inline values of the upper one.
If I disable virtualization in the grid everything works fine.

If created a short example for this scenario.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBlockInDatagridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBlockInDatagridTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgHaupt" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded" Tag="{Binding Test}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      List<Data> systems = new List<Data>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      {
        systems.Add(new Data() { Test = i });
      }

      this.dgHaupt.ItemsSource = systems;

    }

    private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
      if (textBlock == null || (int)textBlock.Tag != 7)
      {
        return;
      }

      textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
      textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("test")
      {
        FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic
      });
    }
  }
struct Data
  {
    public int Test { get; set; }
  }
```

Thank you for all awnsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either disable the virtualization or define the `Run` element in your `DataTemplate` and use data bindings:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgHaupt" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Test" Width="150">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run>
                            <Run.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Run">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Test}" Value="7">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Text" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Run.Style>
                        </Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: In my actual program I have several hyperlinks and text coming from the database. So it's not possible for me to define it directly in xaml. Virtualization can't be deactivated because I have a grid with log entries which will have about 10000 rows.

Comment: Then you can't solve your issue I am afraid :(. Trying to modify the visual element is always a bad idea when virtualization is involved. You have two options and I mentioned both in my answer.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that this is a common issue of virtualization, so I searched much more generally and found a solution.
I just set VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard";
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949358/datagrid-row-virtualization-display-issue