# Displaying lots of data in a WPF Datagrid with PowerShell slows GUI down / hangs

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, user-interface

because of people in my company creating users with umlauts, renaming the samaccountname property on married persons etc. I want to create some basic (or bloated, who knows) GUI for them for just creating/updating the stuff we need. Obviously I cannot provide the og script (company stuff), but I tried to abbreviate the part, that hangs, when loading, filtering, selecting entries etc.

I try to display ~1800 ADGroups in a DataGrid (might not have to display all of them), simulated with a basic loop. For the ScrollBar I use the <ScrollViewer/>. Rest might make more sense when showing code.

WPF:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="AdminPanel_WPFNET.Test_MassiveDataGrid"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AdminPanel_WPFNET"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test_MassiveDataGrid" Height="450" Width="800"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Red.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- Grid Columns for having the Label on the right... -->
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,3">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox x:Name="TxbUserUCGroupFilter" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                         controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"
                         controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                         controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Group Filter">
                    <TextBox.ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                                       FontSize="14"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,5">Group Filter Search!</TextBlock>
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    You can quickly search for a group. Might be a bit too much. Who knows.
                                    <LineBreak />
                                    Action was Enter-Button; Just type the name. Less names, the faster.
                                </TextBlock>
                            </WrapPanel>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Silver"
                                    BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                                    Margin="0,8" />
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}">
                                    ENTER
                                </TextBlock>
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TextBox.ToolTip>
                </TextBox>
                <Label x:Name="LblUserUCGroupCounter" Grid.Column="1" Content="Count Groups: 0"/>
            </Grid>
            <ScrollViewer Height="300">
                <DataGrid d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=3}" x:Name="DgrUserUCGroupMemberships" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      Focusable="False"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor"
                                    Value="Hand" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                         Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                            Value="Blue" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                                         Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background"
                                            Value="Green" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                            Value="Yellow" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                    Value="0" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IsMemberText" Binding="{Binding IsMember}" />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsMemberCHK" Binding="{Binding IsMember}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="GroupName" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

PowerShell:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

#region Paths
# Just test, so no ScriptRoot for now.
$IsDomain = try { (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).PartOfDomain, (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).PartOfDomain | Select-Object -First 1 } catch {}
$BasePath = if (!$IsDomain) { "C:\dev\Projects\Admin-Tools-2022\AdminPanel\AdminPanel" } else { "C:\dev\Projekte\2022_Admin_Tools\AdminPanel\AdminPanel" }
$ProjectPath = "$BasePath\Interface\AdminPanel_WPFNET"
$XAMLFile = Get-Item "$ProjectPath\Test_MassiveDataGrid.xaml"
$AssemblyLocation = "$ProjectPath"
#endregion

#region Load Assemblies needed for testing
$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("PresentationFramework")
    
foreach ($Assembly in (Get-ChildItem $AssemblyLocation -Filter *.dll -Recurse)) {
   Write-Host "Load assembly: $($Assembly.FullName)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
   try {
      $null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($Assembly.FullName)
   }
   catch {
      Write-Host "Error loading '$($Assembly.Name)': $($_.Exception.Message)" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
   }
}
#endregion

#region Load GUI
[xml]$XAML = ( (Get-Content -Path $XAMLFile.FullName -Encoding UTF8) )
$AttributesToRemove = @(
   'x:Class',
   'mc:Ignorable'
)

@(
   "Window",
   "MetroWindow"
) | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Verbose "Removing properties for '$_' ..."
   # Standard: Window, main is MetroWindow this time
   foreach ($Attrib in $AttributesToRemove) {
      if ($XAML."$_") {
         if ($XAML."$_".GetAttribute($Attrib)) {
            $XAML."$_".RemoveAttribute($Attrib)
         }
      }
      else {
         if ($ErrorWhenNotMetro) {
            Write-Host "We do not have a MetroWindow property"
            return
         }
      }
   }
}

# Removing attributes PowerShell cannot load, like the functions called in C#.
$RemoveProperties = @(
   "SelectionChanged"
   "TextChanged"
   "Click"
   "Checked"
   "Unchecked" # not UnChecked
   #"d:ItemsSource" # error!
   "ItemsSource"
)

$XPathString = ($RemoveProperties | ForEach-Object { "@$_" }) -join " or "
Write-Host "Loading XPATH: $XPathString ..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$XAML.SelectNodes("//*[$XPathString]") | ForEach-Object {
   $Node = $_
   $NodeName = $_.Name # e.g.: comboboxName
   $RemoveProperties | ForEach-Object {
      if ($Node.GetAttribute("$_")) {
         Write-Host "Remove attribute '$_' from '$NodeName'" -ForegroundColor Yellow
         $Node.RemoveAttribute("$_")
      }
   }
}
# Sometimes I test things in WPF with SampleData. d:ItemsSource cannot be "translated" by PowerShell by default.
# So I read all d:ItemsSources and remove them this way. Array like above does not work!!
$XAML.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'d:ItemsSource')]]") | ForEach-Object {
   $Node = $_
   $NodeName = $_.Name # e.g.: DgrUserUCGroupMemberships
   if ($Node.GetAttribute("d:ItemsSource")) {
      Write-Host "Remove attribute '$_' from '$NodeName'" -ForegroundColor Magenta
      $Node.RemoveAttribute("d:ItemsSource")
   }
}
Write-Host "/end d:ItemsSource" -ForegroundColor Cyan

# Load XAML after polishing XML-Code
$Reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader)

# Load all variables needed.
$XAML.SelectNodes("//*") | ForEach-Object {
   try {
      Set-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name) -Force -Scope Script
   }
   catch {
      Write-Host "NodeError: $($_.Exception.Message)" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
   }
}
#endregion

#region Actual Functions + Code
$ADGroups = 1..1800 | ForEach-Object {
   [PSCustomObject]@{
      "Name"     = "Group $_"
      "IsMember" = ($true, $false | Get-Random)
   }
}
$DgrUserUCGroupMemberships.AutoGenerateColumns = $false
$DgrUserUCGroupMemberships.ItemsSource = $ADGroups
$LblUserUCGroupCounter.Content = "Group Counter: $($ADGroups.Count)"

$TxbUserUCGroupFilter.Add_TextChanged({
      # Filtering to input text!
      $FilterText = ""
      if ($TxbUserUCGroupFilter.Text) {
         $FilterText = $TxbUserUCGroupFilter.Text
      }
      $FilteredContent = $ADGroups | Where-Object { $_.Name -match "$FilterText" } | Select-Object -First 50
        
      # Converting single object into array!!
      if (($FilteredContent | Measure-Object).Count -eq 1) {
         $FilteredContent = @(, $FilteredContent)
      }
        
      # Nothing found. Preventing errors!
      if (($FilteredContent | Measure-Object).Count -le 0) {
         return
      }
        
      $LblUserUCGroupCounter.Content = "Group Counter: $($FilteredContent.Count)"
      $DgrUserUCGroupMemberships.ItemsSource = $FilteredContent
   })
#endregion

#region Open Window and process its return
if ($Window.ShowDialog()) {
   Write-Host "Successfully processed dialog."
}
else {
   Write-Host "Window/Dialog not processed successfully."
}
#endregion
```

I created the WPF window in Visual Studio Community 2022 (current), with the MahApps.Metro package für creating additional gui controls.

[That's the actual GUI I am experimenting on. Script above is just about the DataGrid groups part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyzJ9.png)

[That's the shorter version with the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJPZy.png)

As many people with "simple" programming questions, I also tried asking ChatGPT. But ChatGPT seems to be confused with using PowerShell, WPF + .Net. It tried to point me to DataPager for Pagination, which should be part of some "WPF Toolkit" in the NuGet PackageManager. I should just add the Assembly "System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.Toolkit", then something with a "PagedCollectionView" (which apparently is part of programming with Silverlight?), then some other page/view collection stuff, which - according to ChatGPT - are part of the PresentationFramework. They are not as it seems.

I guess it is not ready for mixed programming arts.

My guess is, that somehow limiting the output or the rendering of the DataGrid might be some part of the solution, but finding it with PowerShell is not so easy. PowerShell might not be the optimal language to combine with a complicated WPF window, but there must be something. Or maybe I am just too tired or stupid

PS.: My first question here, hope I did good

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remove the scrollviewer round the datagrid and ensure that datagrid ends up with a fixed height less than window content height. I think there's a point you should be making a Wpf app rather than a powershell Wpf app.

Comment: Thanks, that was a huge boost (and a typical "duh" moment). Is it faster because ScrollViewer renders everything while DataGrid does only render what I can see? Yeah, already thought about building a "real" app, but with many PowerShell scripts, WPF is just there. Would you rather build a C# WPF app and then call the PowerShell scripts?

Comment: Not sure what you need to do in powershell. I think powershell Wpf is fine for small simple things. Soon as you need some heavy lifting then I'd suggest that's probably best in a regular desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the datagrid, use Virtualization, as described [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9949812/2582968). Additionally if you can, specify the columns explicitis with

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

and specify the column width explicitly. Otherwise WPF tries to calculate the width based on content.